# Loosing Attributes in DropDownList asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I set attributes into a dropdownlist

the problem is that when I try to read them in a button click I get null !!

I am not sure of this is something to do with the postback or not but you will see my code below

Why is that and how to fix it?

This is my Code

```
    protected void ddlReps_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ddlReps.Items.FindByValue(row["ReportID"].ToString()).Attributes.Add("ReportPath", row["ReportPath"].ToString());
            ddlReps.Items.FindByValue(row["ReportID"].ToString()).Attributes.Add("ReportServer", row["ReportServer"].ToString());
        }
        string AttribValue1 = ddlReps.SelectedItem.Attributes["ReportPath"];
     //When I check here I can see the valu
    }

    protected void btnViewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AttribValue2 = ddlReps.SelectedItem.Attributes["ReportPath"];
     //Here is null :(
    }
```

ALso here is the page load code

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // if the user is already logged in
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
        }


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["USERNAME"] != null) 
            {
                lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome back " + Session["USERNAME"].ToString();
            }
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Main"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            try
            {
                conn.Open(); 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mySP", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 


                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Populate your DropDownList
                    ddlReps.DataSource = dt;
                    ddlReps.DataTextField = "ReportName";
                    ddlReps.DataValueField = "ReportID";
                    ddlReps.DataBind();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Fetch Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
}
```

and here is the markeup for the ddl
the asp:ScriptManager is used because i am using ReportViewer

```
<div>
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

            <div class="report-module">
                <h2>Choose your report</h2>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlReps" runat="server" OnDataBound="ddlReps_DataBound" CssClass="ddl" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:DropDownList> 


            </div>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" ProcessingMode="Remote" Font-Names="sans-serif" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Height="457px" BackColor="White" Visible="False" SplitterBackColor="51, 181, 229">
            </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: show your page_load

Comment: @Webruster I modified the question with the code

Comment: i can see that in your page_load  `{}` are not correct , is it wrong while copying?

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: nevermind , whycan't you keeping the value in `ViewState` instead of `AttribValue1 ` , the reason why you are unable to see the value here is : in your databound method you are looping through the ddlitems and you are adding attribute. but while coming to the click event you are not stating which `item no` attribute you need .. that is the reason you are seeing it as null

Comment: what do you mean  not stating which item no attribute you need? I choose SelectedItem also I tried ddlReps.Items[0].Attributes["ReportPath"]; and still getting NULL

Comment: show me your ddl markup

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150364/discussion-between-webruster-and-asmgx).